# Contour integral of modulus of a sequence of analytic function converges to zero implies the function converges to zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Consider a sequence of function $\{f_n(z)\}_{n \geq 1}$ defined on complex space $z \in \mathbb{C},$ and assume for each $n$, $f_n$ is analytic in $\{|z|<1 \}$, and continuous on $\{ |z|\leq 1\},$ and the following property holds
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f_n(e^{i\theta})| d \theta =0.
\end{equation}
I want to show that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \max_{|z| \leq 1} |f_{n}(z)| =0.
\end{equation}

My attempt is to use maximum modulus principle for analytic functions. If the statement is wrong, then there exists a subsequence ${f}_{n_k}$ and a positive constant $\epsilon_0$ such that $\max_{|z| \leq 1} |f_{n}(z)|=|f_n(z_n)| \geq \epsilon_0.$ Clearly $z_n \in \{ |z|=1 \}$. I want to show that
$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f_{n_k}(e^{i\theta})| d \theta$ does not tend to $0$, but I am stuck here. Can anyone give me some advice?

$\textbf{Update}$：GEdgar has given a counterexample. Now I would like to prove that, for a given 0<r<1, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n} \max_{|z| \leq r} \ | f_n(z) |=0.
\end{equation}

Comment: This last follows by Cauchy since for fixed $r<1$ one has $|f_n(z)| \le \frac{||f_n||_1}{1-r}$ for $|z|\le r$

Comment: Yes，thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

In general, $L^1$ convergence does not imply $L^\infty$ convergence.  So, to see that using analytic functions does not change this:
Just fiddle around a bit.  Try
$$
f_n(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(1-(1-1/n)z)}, \quad n=2,3,4,\dots .
$$
So $f_n$ is analytic except at $\frac{n}{n-1} > 1$.  And
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} |f_n(e^{i\theta})|\,d\theta
=\frac{4\sqrt{n}}{2n-1}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{n^2-n}}{2n-1}\right)
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f_n(e^{i\theta})|\,d\theta = 0
$$
but
$$
f_n(1) = \sqrt{n}
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\max_{|z|\le 1}|f_n(z)| = \infty
$$

---

We used this notation for the elliptic integral $K$:
$$
K(k) = \int_0^1 \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{1-k z^2}} ,
$$
so Mathematica's $K$ is $K[k^2] = K(k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your great counterexample, while I notice that, in your example above, for a given 0<r<1, we have $\lim_n  \max_{|z|≤r} |f_n(z)|=0$ ,
 so can I prove this weaker conclusion holds? ( I have edited my question.)